# Add data from column "A" into ''ComboBox1" when data is updated

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have a Catalogue that contains hardware in a Sheet called "Catalogus_Hardware". All the hardware is located in column A.

I want that hardware to show up in my ComboBox called ComboBox1.

I have it "configured" like this:

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
With Me.ComboBox1
    .Clear
    .AddItem ""
    .AddItem "Device1
    .AddItem "Device2"
    .AddItem "Device3"
    .AddItem "Device4"
End With
Call Refresh_Data
End Sub
```

Adding an item one by one takes too much time.

I want when I update my catalogue it automatically updates the hardware in my ComboBox as well.

Comment: what about giving a name to the hardware range and assign that name to your combobox?

Comment: How do you mean @FrederikGysel. I'm not 100% sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

give a name to your list with hardware:

[image]

(you can change the range of the list on sheet change to make sure latest added hardware is added)

Assign that name to the input range of your combo box:

[image]

[image]

Comment: * I forgot to mention that i'm using that ComboBox in a Form.

Comment: VBA: ComboBox1.List = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Names("hardware").RefersToRange)

Answer (score 0):

I feel so stupid xD. I Just changed the RowSource in the properties of my ComboBox and tadaaaa. . But thank you for your help Frederik :D